# How to programmatically get/access/identify HDMI port on video Adapter

Tags: c++, windows, direct3d, dxgi

My requirement is to render frames over HDMI so that it can be displayed on  the attached output display device as an overlay on its Video. My researched showed that Direct3D DXGI will be a good  approach to achieve  the frames rendering. So i worked on it and learnt how can we render frames using Direct3D .Moreover, to render the frames I am able to enumerate the graphics adapter and find its details. However my further research revealed that in order to render the frame over HDMI i need to identify the HDMI port of the graphics adapter so that i can pass that frame over hdmi and get it rendered. That is where I have been stuck for quite a while now. Any suggestions or piece of code  or any other approach through which i can achieve rendering the frames over HDMI on to output display device will be really appreciated.

Comment: What? Do you mean you want to render some graphics on a desktop that shows on a display connected over HDMI? How is that different from any other rendering? Just make sure your desktop is set to expand the desktop area between all of the displays and that's it.

Comment: @Luaan: I am a newbie  on this platform..Please excuse me in case i ask anything silly..:)  Do you mean i need to extend the display to other displays because i don't require that..I need to render the frame over HDMI to the connected TV and don't want to display my desktop on TV screen...just want that frame to be visible there on TV with TV's own background there...I hope that might make it a little more clear..

Comment: Yup, that made it a lot more clear. You can't do that :)

Comment: @Luaan: Any specific reasons for that?? Isn't there any way out or work around for this at all??

Comment: It's not a problem of the computer - it's on the TV side. Unless you've got some special piece of hardware there, TV's don't overlay multiple input signals. There's some limited related technologies (e.g. PIP), but I'm not sure if that will help you.

Comment: @Gdroid did you find any solution ?